# Toggling lottie hamburger/menu animation on .nav-link click?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, lottie

## SOLVED, SEE MY SOLUTION BELOW

Hello so my navigation works fine like this apart from when the links are clicked, the lottie animation doesn't toggle back to it's first frame.

Could anyone help me with a solution to this as I've been trying for awhile now with no luck.

I'm using bootstrap and this is my navigation toggler button:

```
<button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#lowetoggle"
        aria-controls="lowetoggle"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
      <div class="lowe-menu" style="width: 50px;"></div>
      </button>
<lottie-player id="toggleLottie" src="assets/menu.json" style="width:50px;">"></lottie-player>
</button>
```

and this is my js:

```
let iconMenu = document.querySelector('.lowe-menu');

let animationMenu = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
        container: iconMenu,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        path: "/assets/menu.json"
});

var directionMenu = 1;
  iconMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  animationMenu.setDirection(directionMenu);
  animationMenu.play();
  directionMenu = -directionMenu;
});

var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')
var menuToggle = document.getElementById('lowetoggle')
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle:false})

navLinks.forEach((l) => {
    l.addEventListener('click', () => { bsCollapse.toggle() })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bootstrap 5 Lottie Hamburger Menu

Solved this myself, So if you are using Lottie for your hamburger menu in Bootstrap, and your page is using anchor links to scroll to different sections, this code will make the hamburger close on clicking a .nav-link element.

Hope this is useful, as I've not found anyone else with a snippet for this online! Maybe I didn't far though!

```js
let iconMenu = document.querySelector('.lowe-menu');

    let animationMenu = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
            container: iconMenu,
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: false,
            autoplay: false,
            animationData: {"v":"5.7.4","fr":60,"ip":0,"op":39,"w":600,"h":600,"nm":"hamburger to x","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":3,"nm":"ScaleCTRL","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[300,300,0],"ix":2,"l":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1,"l":2},"s":{"a":0,"k":[391.026,391.026,100],"ix":6,"l":2}},"ao":0,"ip":0,"op":39,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"Line03","parent":1,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"t":24,"s":[0]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":32,"s":[48]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":37,"s":[45]},{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"t":47,"s":[45]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":52,"s":[48]},{"t":60,"s":[0]}],"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.667,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":15,"s":[0,30.5,0],"to":[0,-5.083,0],"ti":[0,5.083,0]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"t":24,"s":[0,0,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.667,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":60,"s":[0,0,0],"to":[0,5.083,0],"ti":[0,-5.083,0]},{"t":69,"s":[0,30.5,0]}],"ix":2,"l":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[-9.75,-20,0],"ix":1,"l":2},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6,"l":2}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-63,-20],[43.5,-20]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":15,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":39,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":3,"ty":4,"nm":"Line02","parent":1,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":2,"l":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[-9.75,-20,0],"ix":1,"l":2},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6,"l":2}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-63,-20],[43.5,-20]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":15,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.411],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.938],"y":[0]},"t":1,"s":[0]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":20,"s":[50]},{"i":{"x":[0.411],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.938],"y":[0]},"t":58,"s":[50]},{"t":78,"s":[0]}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.411],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.938],"y":[0]},"t":1,"s":[100]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":20,"s":[50]},{"i":{"x":[0.411],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.938],"y":[0]},"t":58,"s":[50]},{"t":78,"s":[100]}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":39,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":4,"ty":4,"nm":"Line01","parent":1,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"t":24,"s":[0]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":32,"s":[-48]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":37,"s":[-45]},{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"t":47,"s":[-45]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"t":52,"s":[-48]},{"t":60,"s":[0]}],"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.667,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":15,"s":[0,-30.5,0],"to":[0,5.083,0],"ti":[0,-5.083,0]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"t":24,"s":[0,0,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.667,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":60,"s":[0,0,0],"to":[0,-5.083,0],"ti":[0,5.083,0]},{"t":69,"s":[0,-30.5,0]}],"ix":2,"l":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[-9.75,-20,0],"ix":1,"l":2},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6,"l":2}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-63,-20],[43.5,-20]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":15,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":39,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
    });

    var directionMenu = 1;
      iconMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      animationMenu.setDirection(directionMenu);
      animationMenu.play();
      directionMenu = -directionMenu;
    });
    
    var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')
    var menuToggle = document.getElementById('lowetoggle')
    var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle:false})
    
    navLinks.forEach((l) => {
    l.addEventListener('click', () => { 
        if (window.innerWidth < 992){ // This part fixes flickering on desktop nav-items!
            bsCollapse.toggle()
            animationMenu.setDirection(directionMenu);
            animationMenu.play();
            directionMenu = -directionMenu;
        }
     });
});
```

```css
.navbar-lowe {background-color: black;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-lowe">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <p>Logo</p>
          </a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#lowetoggle"
            aria-controls="lowetoggle"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
          <div class="lowe-menu" style="width: 50px;"></div>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="lowetoggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav align-items-end">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-text ms-auto text-end">
              <a class="btn nav-button" role="button">Call Today <strong>05555555 555</strong></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.8.1/lottie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```